# How to stop executing roles if the OS versions are different with in inventory

Tags: ansible

I have two different Centos versions 6.x and 7.x in my Inventory. I am able to print OS versions using below code

```
 - name: Get OS details
   debug: msg="{{ item }}"
   with_items:
   - "{{ ansible_distribution_version }}"
```

1. How to stop executing remaining roles if OS version is 7 instead of 6 or vice versa? I have all my inventory in one file.
2. If i'm running the code against version 6 then it needs to print the hostnames if it's not version 6 and stop executing remaining roles.

Comment: You can use `if` condition in ansible for this.  `ansible_distribution_version` this is ansible facts.

Comment: I've tried registering the output of ansible_distribution_version and used when but no luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Abort execution of remaining task if certain condition is failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758925/abort-execution-of-remaining-task-if-certain-condition-is-failed)

Comment: @error404 - are you referring to the `when` keyword or something else?

Comment: when statement i'm using

Comment: @DavidMedinets no I was referring to `when:` condition only. Used `if` as in general. I will be more specific with the code henceforth :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `meta` option, `end_play`, for example

```
- name: end play if not centos6
  meta: end_play
  when: ansible_distribution_version == "centos6"
```

More information in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html

---

what you probably want to do is split your setup tasks into `tasks/centos6.yml` and `tasks/centos7.yml` and only include the relevant file in your playbook, for example

```
- name: setup centos7
  include: tasks/centos7.yml
  when: ansible_distribution_version == centos7
```