# Ansible 2.9: how to CONTINUE with the rest of the tasks if a condition is not satisfied

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to modify a playbook called "`upgradeTomcat.yaml`" written by someone else and I want to insert a piece of code right in the middle of a playbook, between tasks "`check git`" and "`check tomcat`" like this:

```
- name: check git
...
[my intended code here]
...
- name: check tomcat
...
```

What I want to insert is this: check if Tomcat is already installed on the remote server and if NOT, then invoke a separate "`installTomcatOnly.yam`l" playbook with "`include_tasks`" directive **and once that playbook finished**, stop the execution of the rest of the tasks in "`upgradeTomcat.yaml`".

But if Tomcat is already installed, then proceed with the rest of the tasks in "`upgradeTomcat.yaml`", without invoking "`installTomcatOnly.yaml`" playbook.

How do I tell Ansible to CONTINUE with the rest of the tasks if a certain condition is not satisfied?

UPDATE. Here is the actual code that I inserted into "`upgradeTomcat.yaml`" playbook with which I check if Tomcat is installed:

```
- name: Check if Tomcat is installed
  shell: ls -l /opt/tomcat/|grep "[ ]\+{{ newTomcatVer }}$"; echo $?
  register: tomcatExists

- block:

  - name: "Invoking another PLAYBOOK"
    include_tasks: installTomcatOnly.yaml
  when: tomcatExists is defined and tomcatExists.rc == "1"
```

Right after this code, the playbook continues with another task ("Check extracted version"):

```
- name: Check extracted version
  shell: ls -latr /opt/tomcat/|grep "[^>][ ]\+apache-tomcat-[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+$"|grep -o "[^ ]*$"; echo $?
  ...
```

So I ran the playbook against a server on which there is no Tomcat but instead of invoking "`installTomcatOnly.yaml`" playbook, the original "`upgradeTomcat.yaml`" continued to play, despite the "`end_play`" directive:

```
TASK [Check if Tomcat is installed] *****************************************************************************************************************   
changed: [tomcat@server]

TASK [Invoking another PLAYBOOK] ********************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [tomcat@server]

TASK [Check extracted version] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [tomcat@server]

^C [ERROR]: User interrupted execution
```

The contents of "`installTomcatOnly.yaml`" are:

```
---
  - name: Check if Tomcat is installed
    debug:
      msg: "This message is from another PLAYBOOK"
    meta: end_play
```

The command I used to run the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook roles/tomcatUpgradeHarden/tasks/upgradeTomcat.yaml --extra-vars "host_group=tomcat@server newTomcatVer=apache-tomcat-8.5.69"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758925/abort-execution-of-remaining-task-if-certain-condition-is-failed

Comment: What's the logic to determine if Tomcat is installed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have figured out your logic to determine whether tomcat is installed or not, register that as a variable. Use that variable as a condition for calling your playbook. For ease, in the example below I have assumed your tomcat installed logic registers a Boolean variable.

```yaml
  # ... logic to calculate tomcat installation here
  register: is_tomcat_installed

- import_playbook: installTomcatOnly.yaml
  when: not is_tomcat_installed

  # ... The rest of the playbook
```

Then at the end of `installTomcatOnly.yaml`, insert the `meta: end_play` task, which will end the play without an error.

This way, your `installTomcatOnly` playbook will run if tomcat is not installed, then end before running the rest of `upgradeTomcat`. Otherwise, this will all be conditionally skipped and `upgradeTomcat` playbook will run till its completion without running any of `installTomcatOnly`.

##### UPDATE:

The reason your playbook tasks from `installTomcatOnly.yaml` were not running is because they were being skipped, because your conditional logic was not correct.

Your current shell command is bugged - running `echo $?` will always be a success regardless of what the previous status code is, meaning that the output status code of your command will always be `0`. Here's an example:

```
$ false


$ echo $?
1

$ echo $?
0
```

You are also comparing the return code to the string value of "1", not the numeric value of 1, which will not work. These two reasons are why your code is skipping the imported playbook.

This should work:

```yaml
- name: Check if Tomcat is installed
  shell: ls -l /opt/tomcat/ | grep "[ ]\+{{ newTomcatVer }}$"
  register: tomcat_exists
  failed_when: tomcat_exists.rc > 1

- block:
  name: Invoking another PLAYBOOK
    include_tasks: installTomcatOnly.yaml
  when: tomcat_exists.rc == 1
```

Comment: thanks for the advise. As it turned out, i cannot use "import_playbook" within "tasks" context, so i had to use "include_tasks " instead. But somehow Ansible ignores the external playbook when I try to  invoke it. I updated by original post with the actual code

Comment: @kamokoba I've updated my answer in response to your update 

Comment: I'm getting this error:

 "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1'

when i remove the "; echo $?" part from the "shell" value.
I tested this shell command (with "; echo $?" part at the end" ) and it works as expected - it always returns "1" if apache-tomat folder is found and "0" if not.
And I did change the string value of "1" to the integer 1, but still the invoked playbook is being skipped. Strange

Comment: I've updated my answer again @kamokoba, let me know if this doesn't work. Specifically, add a `failed_when` attribute to the first task

Comment: It works now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use assert or fail.

OR

In Ansible 2.2+ there is the meta module:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/meta_module.html

> meta: end_play

Stop the playbook with a non failing status.